# Getting unsupported operand type error while trying to subtract two date values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am not why I am getting error in below code -

```
from datetime import datetime
import time
start =datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0).isoformat(' ')
end = datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0).isoformat(' ')
print(f" Total Time taken by check run is {end - start}[hh:mm:ss]")
```

Error is coming in the print statement saying:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

Answer (score 2):

`isoformat()` returns a `string`.

If you remove `isoformat()` from your `datetime object`, you will be able to subtract the time difference.

```
start = datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
end = datetime(2021, 4, 9, 17, 15, 00)
print(f" Total Time taken by check run is {end - start}[hh:mm:ss]")

#Total Time taken by check run is 1:26:18[hh:mm:ss]
```